# Determining normalizing constant for Weibull distribution

Tags: density-function, weibull-distribution, stan

I am fitting a Weibull distribution to some data in Stan. I am trying to reproduce some published values of parameters from a paper. However I am running into problems because I believe the normalizing constant does not match. The paper gives the pdf equation as follows:

$p(x|\mu,\nu) = \frac{1}{K} (\frac{x}{\nu})^{\mu - 1} exp(-(\frac{x}{\nu})^{\mu})$

However the Weibull pdf in Stan is:

$p(x|\mu,\nu) = \frac{\mu}{\nu} (\frac{x}{\nu})^{\mu - 1} exp(-(\frac{x}{\nu})^{\mu})$

When I fit the distribution to the same data as the paper, I get different fitted values for the shape and scale parameters ($\mu$ and $\nu$) than the ones in the paper, but the paper gives no indication of how to find the normalizing constant K. Is there a way to determine the correct value for the constant so that I can get the correct values of shape and scale parameters?

Here is the (very simple) Stan model I fit:

```
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector<lower=0>[N] x;
}

parameters {
    // Weibull density
    real<lower=0> mu;
    real<lower=0> nu;
}

model {
    // Priors: Weibull density
    mu ~ lognormal(1, 1);
    nu ~ lognormal(1, 1);

    // Likelihood: Weibull density
    x ~ weibull(mu, nu);
}
```

Comment: I'm also interested, in a more general sense, in whether improperly specifying the normalizing constant would cause different parameter values to be fit.

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: @JarleTufto Unfortunately it's behind a paywall but here is the link (the relevant thing is equation 4b): http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1461-0248.2006.00915.x/abstract

Comment: As far as I understand, what they are fitting are truncated weibull distributions with a lower truncation point $D_0>0$ being the size (diameter) at recruitment.  So this leads to a different normalizing constant (some function of $\nu$, $\mu$ and $D_0$ that they derive in Appendix S1), also different from what is used by Stan which only has the non-truncated distribution built in I guess.

Comment: @ Jarle Tufto is it possible to specify the log pdf of truncated Weibull manually in Stan?

Comment: Apparently yes, see section 12.2 in the manual.

Comment: @JarleTufto I believe I almost have it but I am stuck on the derivation of the normalizing constant in appendix S1. I cannot determine how to express it as a function of $\mu$, $\nu$, and $D_0$.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding this question, because doesn't comparing the two expressions you give for $p$ immediately show $K=\nu/\mu$? If you're getting different parameter estimates than the paper, then--assuming the paper is correct and you are using Stan correctly--that's not due to the normalizing constant.  Unfortunately, you don't supply any information that would help us even guess what the issue really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the answer you are looking for is to change your likelihood statement to

```
for (i in 1:N) x[i] ~ weibull(mu, nu) T[L, ];
```

where `L` is the lower truncation point. But you should not actually do it that way. Stan arrives at that answer by subtracting the logarithm of the complimentary CDF evaluated at `L`. Thus, it is equivalent (and faster) to write

```
target += weibull_lpdf(x | mu, nu) - N * weibull_lccdf(L | mu, nu);
```

presuming that `L` is a scalar truncation point that applies to all `N` observations. Chapter 12 of the Stan User Manual has more examples.

If you actually want to see the math, you can use the Mathematica syntax

```
PowerExpand[Log[FullSimplify[ PDF[WeibullDistribution[\[Mu],\[Nu]], x] / (1 - CDF[WeibullDistribution[\[Mu],\[Nu]], L]), Assumptions->{x>0, L>0}]]]
```

which evaluates to

```
(L^\[Mu]-x^\[Mu]) \[Nu]^-\[Mu]-Log[x]+Log[\[Mu]]+\[Mu] (Log[x]-Log[\[Nu]])
```

Comment: can you specify a lower and upper truncation like this: `target += weibull_lpdf(x | mu, nu) - N * weibull_lccdf(L | mu, nu) - N * weibull_lccdf(U | mu, nu);` @Ben Goodrich

Comment: For two-sided truncation, you need to divide the PDF by the probability of being on the (L, U) interval, which is the CDF evaluated at U minus the CDF evaluated at L. And then take the logarithm because Stan uses the log-kernel. So, it would be `target += weibull_lpdf(x | mu, nu) - N * log(weibull_cdf(U | mu, nu) - weibull_cdf(L | mu, nu))`. Again, that is assuming `U` and `L` are scalars. If not, then you have to do the correction one observation at a time or analytically work out the log of the difference in the CDFs to hopefully obtain an expression that can be vectorized.

Comment: This is the way that ended up working for me. After fitting the truncated Weibull in Stan with both a lower limit `ll` and upper limit `ul` and outputting predicted values in R, I divided the predicted values by `sum(1 - pweibull(q = c(ll,ul), shape, scale))` which rescales the area under the truncated Weibull to 1. @Ben Goodrich apologies for not officially awarding the bounty, I was out of town and missed the deadline.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get easy access to it the book *The Weibull Distribution: A Handbook* by Horst Rinne covers the general three parameter Weibull down to the one. There is also a section on the truncated Weibull distributions. You may want to consult it for how different parameterizations are derived.